# send push notifications to a specific channel

Tags: android, parse-platform, channel

Assuming I subscribed to more then one channel, how can I send a message to a specific channel?

I used this lines:

```
push.setMessage(msg);
push.sendInBackground();
```

I also tried to use the line `push.setChannel(SPECIFIC CHANNEL);` but it didn't work....

but obviously it's not enough since it sends the message to all channels.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the channel you would like to push to.

```
  public void pushData(String channel, String Message) {
    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setChannel(channel);
    push.setMessage(Message);
    push.sendInBackground();
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know the JSON structure of that object?  Looking at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref and the available options are `data` and `notification`.  Would `channelId` be within one of those objects?